# InstanceAnnotation into OData Response

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I defined follow own provider:

```
public class CustomEntityTypeSerializer : ODataEntityTypeSerializer
{
    public CustomEntityTypeSerializer(ODataSerializerProvider serializerProvider)
        : base(serializerProvider)
    {}

    public override Microsoft.OData.Core.ODataEntry CreateEntry(SelectExpandNode selectExpandNode, EntityInstanceContext entityInstanceContext)
    {
        Microsoft.OData.Core.ODataEntry entry = base.CreateEntry(selectExpandNode, entityInstanceContext);

        entry.InstanceAnnotations.Add(new ODataInstanceAnnotation("org.test", new ODataPrimitiveValue("test")));
        return entry;
    }

}
```

and I can't get instance annotations above within http response from my webapi app.
Why it is occurs?

ps: I use System.Web.OData lib from latest release of master branch from aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com. Accept header with odata.metadata=full is enable

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if header of response contains:

```
Preference-Applied: odata.include-annotations="*"
```

If not, try to pass the following Prefer header in your request header. Let service handle this header and return the response with above Preference-Applied header.

```
Prefer: odata.include-annotations="*"
```

ODL writer should write instance annotations with the setting of odata.include-annotations in Preference-Applied header

Comment: I have tried _odata.include-annotations="*"_ and _odata.include-annotations=*_ value for _Prefer_ header, but there is no effect. Response header doesn't have _Preference-Applied_ header as well.

Comment: Ok, that means service does not handle the Prefer header auto. do you have the right to set response header in web-api service? Unless setting preference-applied header in response header(no matter you or service do), the instance annotation will not be written...

Comment: I have defined custom EnableQuery attribute in my solution and introduced Preference-Applied header within response (from actionContext) on OnActionExecuted event. As well I have been convinced that call attends to overridden method. But I haven't received expected result: in response header have appeared without effect on response body

Comment: Have you anyone idea else? :)